# How do I read a file and compare user input to see if it matches? C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to get input and compare it to a doc to see if it matches anything in the doc. Though I am having issues passing variables around. Line keeps popping back in the albumComp function as not defined even though it's being passed in main.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// function prototype for user input comparison to doc
void albumComp(string);
// function prototype for user input taken
void input(string);

int main() {
  fstream albums("albums.txt", ios::in);
  string fileContent;
  string line;

  if (albums) {
    while (albums >> line) {
      albumComp(line);
    }

  } else {
    cout << "Unable to open file\n";
  }
  albums.close();
  return 0;
}

/*This function gathers the albums for comparisons from
the user to pass that into albumComp()*/

void input(string input) {
  cout << "Please enter the album you want test\n";
  cin >> input;
}

/*This function compares the user input of album
to the contents of the Doc to see if it is already present */

void albumComp(string userInput) {
  input(userInput);
  cout << line;
  cout << userInput;
}
```

Comment: If you want to read lines, use `std::getline()`. Otherwise your file stream stops at the first whitespace it finds, like spaces.

Comment: Your function calls are out of whack.

Comment: You should provide a sample file's contents, and the exact text of the error you are currently receiving. See [ask]. Also see [mre] and take the [tour] while you're at it.

Answer (score -1):

This is the flow of your program:

- In your `main()`, you call `albumComp(line)` where `line` is what you read from the file.
- `albumComp()` calls `input(userInput)`, but your variable `userInput` is the line you read from the file
- Your function `input()` prompts the user to enter an album name, and you store it in `input`, which is overwriting a **copy** of the line you read from the file. It is then promptly destroyed as the function ends.
- Back in `albumComp()`, you attempt to `std::cout << line;` even though the variable `line` **does not exist** within the scope of the function.
- You then try to print `userInput`, which would just be the line you read from the file.

There are lots of ways around this, but the main thing is to ensure that your functions are singular in purpose. `albumComp()` is trying to get input **and** compare albums. Don't do that. Get the input in your `main()`, and change `albumComp()` to take two 'albums' to compare.

Understanding function return values and the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference will also come in handy.